# ¿Cómo modificar permisos o propiedades de seguridad de un PDF previamente firmado con iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, itextsharp

Tengo un servicio dónde se firma un documento, pero necesito que cuando el último en firmar sea el presente, el archivo PDF modifique algunas propiedades de seguridad del documento sin que se dañe la firma, puesto que encriptando la firma muere.